# Embed view localization in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, localization, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a ASP.NET website. I successfully managed to load embed views from another project, but I can't get localization to run. It works fine with views from the startup assembly but when loading the embed ones there is a error message:

> InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization.IHtmlLocalizer' has been registered.

The code for the view is as following:

_ViewImports.cshtml (embed):

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@inject IHtmlLocalizer Localizer
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Index.cshtml (embed)

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = Localizer["Home"];
}

<div>
    @Localizer["Test"]
</div>
```

My startup.cs (in the main project) looks like this:

```
namespace My.Name.Space //Not the real one
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            //Standard builder function
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

            //Add EF DbContext, identity, etc.

            services.AddMvc()
                .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
                .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

            //Localization

            var supportedCultures = GetListOfCultures();

            services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "en-US", uiCulture: "en-US");
                options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
            });
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            var locOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
            app.UseRequestLocalization(locOptions.Value);

            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseBrowserLink();
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");

                // For more details on creating database during deployment see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=615859
                try
                {
                    using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>()
                        .CreateScope())
                    {
                        serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>()
                             .Database.Migrate();
                    }
                }
                catch { }
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseIdentity();

            // To configure external authentication please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                // Areas support
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "areaRoute",
                    template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something or is it a bug in RC2?

Greetings,

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem with my application upgrading from RC1 to RC2.

I changed

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
```

to

```
services.AddLocalization();
```

You need to have your *.resx files in the Resources folder of your Web project for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I put

```
@inject IHtmlLocalizer Localizer
```

instead of

```
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
```

Thanks,